# Angular running error Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I have  Angular application with several npm dependency in package.json. When i try to install the npm dependency `npm i` getting some `sha1 seems to be corrupted issue`. For that I delete the package-lock.json and then i can install all the npm dependency successfully. But `npm start` can't able to run the application showing error as

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
```

Error log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.15.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle ruf-stable@0.0.0~prestart: ruf-stable@0.0.0
6 info lifecycle ruf-stable@0.0.0~start: ruf-stable@0.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle ruf-stable@0.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle ruf-stable@0.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\workspace\myworkspace\2020\fis-employee-ui\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_212\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\;C:\Users\e5608029\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\;C:\Users\e5608029\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\;C:\Users\e5608029\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\e5608029\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\e5608029\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
9 verbose lifecycle ruf-stable@0.0.0~start: CWD: C:\workspace\myworkspace\2020\fis-employee-ui
10 silly lifecycle ruf-stable@0.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c',
10 silly lifecycle   'ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --proxy-config proxy.conf.json' ]
11 info lifecycle ruf-stable@0.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
12 verbose stack Error: ruf-stable@0.0.0 start: `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`
12 verbose stack spawn ENOENT
12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:48:18)
12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
12 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
12 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
13 verbose pkgid ruf-stable@0.0.0
14 verbose cwd C:\workspace\myworkspace\2020\fis-employee-ui
15 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
16 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
17 verbose node v10.15.0
18 verbose npm  v6.4.1
19 error file C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno ENOENT
22 error syscall spawn
23 error ruf-stable@0.0.0 start: `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`
23 error spawn ENOENT
24 error Failed at the ruf-stable@0.0.0 start script.
24 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question has to do with its title. My advice would be to delete your node_modules directory and the redo an `npm install`

Comment: I had the same problem with my angular@7 project after updating the CLI globally to version 8 and solve it by upgrading angular in my project to the latest version by running this command in my project directory:

`ng update @angular/cli @angular/core`

Answer (score 1):

Try npm install again after deleting the existing file. then retry npm start. if still not working try to upgrade your project by 'ng update @angular/cli @angular/core' Command.
you have to do few more changed as mentioned [here](https://update.angular.io/#7.0:8.0)